# Why invoking class method from DLL requires virtual specifier?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have weird issue while trying to call a method from loaded DLL.

Lets start with simple `Log` class with method Write taking `const char*` argument.

```cpp
class ENGINE_API Log
{
private:
    const char* Category;

public:
    Log(const char* Category);

    void Write(const char* format, ...);
};
```

The class is marked by `__declspec` (using the **ENGINE_API** macro) as `dllexport` while building it inside "owner" DLL and marked as `dllimport` while using only header during build of another DLL.

Also the first "owner" DLL have exported extern C function called `CreateLogInstance` which simply creates instance of `Log` class and returns it.

```cpp
PUBLIC_FUNCTION Log* CreateLogInstance(const char* name)
{
    return new Log(name);
}
```

In the second DLL I call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` with correct cast to a function pointer. Than I simply calls the `Write` method with some text.

```cpp
typedef Log*(*CreateLogInstanceFunction)(const char*);

HINSTANCE moduleHandle = LoadLibrary("Engine.dll");
CreateLogInstanceFunction createLogInstanceFunction = (CreateLogInstanceFunction)GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "CreateLogInstanceWithName");

// omitting the null checks etc

Output = createLogInstanceFunction("Game");
Output->Write("Hello Game");
```

Everything works fine with one requirement which is - the `Write` method must be marked as `virtual`, if is not the compilation it self fails on *LNK2019 unresolved external symbol error* on line where `Write` method is invoked.

I don't need it to be `virtual` in my case (for some polymorphism) and my question is - why is the `virtual` specifier required in order to get this work?

This also works (without `virtual` specifier) when I choose to use **Load-Time Dynamic Linking** and link during build against .lib file, but I like to stick with **Run-Time Dynamic Linking**.

Thank you.

*Using Windows 10 (1809) and Visual Studio 2019 with latest Windows SDK.*

Comment: are you include *lib* file to exe build ? think that no. and what sense some function import via  dynamic link and another via `GetProcAddress` ? include lib file and not use *GetProcAddress*. of use *GetProcAddress* for every exported function

Comment: and which your windows version, which you vs version, are you use vs - absolute unrelated here

Comment: when you use *virtual* (say `Write` is *virtual* method) - `Output->Write` called via vtable on object. when you not use *virtual* - from where you get `Write` address ? (now it not exist in vtable). or via `GetProcAddress` or via import table. you not do any of this

Comment: RbMm is right. Address of a function is determined in compile time, but code for `Log::Write` is not actually compiled in the second DLL. You should not export C++ stuff (like Log class). Instead `CreateLogInstance` should return `void*` and some new function `Log_Write` should take two parameters, `void*` and `const char*`.

Comment: @Dialecticus: It's perfectly fine to export C++-stuff. What one should not do is exporting c++ STL-stuff (compiler and version dependency) !

Comment: @Dialecticus - *Address of a function is determined in compile time* - this is false. if function marked as `__declspec(dllimport)` - it address is init in run-time by loader. compiler call it via pointer, which is initialized when *pe* is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for call function from external module we need have address of this function.

if we mark function as *virtual* - inside object exist pointer to table (so called *vftable*) where stored pointers to all virtual functions for this object. and compiler generate appropriate code for call function via this pointer.

so when you write

```
class log
{
public:
    virtual void Write(const char* format, ...);
};
```

compiler generate hidden struct *vftable* inside object

```
class log
{
public:
    virtual void Write(const char* format, ...);

    struct vftable {
        void (* Write)(const char* format, ...);
    };
};
```

and call

```
Output->Write("Hello Game");
```

really implemented as

```
(*(log::vftable**)Output)->Write("Hello Game");
```

so here we have object pointer (*Output*), inside it exist pointer to *log::vftable*, and inside this table exist pointer to *Write* function. note that in this case we not need mark class as *dllexport* or *dllimport*

this is why work with *virtual* functions - all what you need to call *virtual* function - pointer to object.

in case function not *virtual* - and marked as *__declspec(dllimport)* compiler declare hidden variable, which is hold pointer to function. and function will be called via this variable. so when we write:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) log
{
public:
    virtual void Write(const char* format, ...);
};

void demo(log* Output)
{
    Output->Write("Hello Game");
}
```

compiler actually do next:

```
extern void (* __imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ)(log* This, const char* format, ...);

void demo(log* Output)
{
    __imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ(Output, "Hello Game");
}
```

note that pointer to function *__imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ* only declared (with *extern*) but not implemented. if you build without appropriate *lib* file (where implemented *__imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ* symbol) you got linker error : *unresolved external symbol __imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ*

so if member function declare without *virtual* and class declared as *__declspec(dllimport)* you need use appropriate *lib*. loader, when load your *PE* get exported *?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ* function address from *Engine.dll* and write this address to *__imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ*

of course exist else one option - implement all this yourself. take for self job of loader. something like this

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ=?__imp__Write_log__QEAAXPEBDZZ@@3PEAXEA")

void* __imp__Write_log__QEAAXPEBDZZ = 0;

BOOL LoadEngine()
{
    if (HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryW(L"Engine.dll"))
    {
        if (__imp__Write_log__QEAAXPEBDZZ = GetProcAddress(hmod, "?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ"))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

after this we already can call `Output->Write("Hello Game");`

of course in *c++* we can not direct declare name *__imp_?Write@log@@QEAAXPEBDZZ* so need use trick with linker option */alternatename*. or we can declare this name exactly in separate *asm* file

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Not sure if this is not out of the scope of my original question but - if I use dllimport/dllexport and link against .lib file it will create "hard" dependency in DLL/exe to another one, based on dumpbin output, which is fine. But if I don't want to make that "hard" dependency and load/link in runtime I have to use LoadLibrary and virtual methods in order to keep code clean without using "magic" stuff like linker alternate name etc. Is that correct?

Comment: @Wefod - i try describe how this is implemented. you neen have pointer to function for call it. or use *virtual* functions, by fact you need implement pure com interface and call all via this interface, or you need implement variables, which will be hold pointers to member functions. and init it via GetProcAddress

Comment: Got it. Will be `virtual` variant slow? I mean, if that function is called many times lets say 60 times per second, it will be noticeable performance hit compared to dllimport/dllexport and linking with .lib? But I suppose this is project specific, so maybe I should test it by myself. Also thank you for your time.

Comment: @Wefod - no, *virtual* will be not slow. 60 times per second - this is nothing. yes, 2 additional instructions per call, but this is nothing really